# how to perform these queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these three tables:

```
create table albums(sernum number primary key, 
        Albname varchar2(30) not null,
        Artist varchar2(20) not null,
        Pdate number(4),
        Recompany varchar2(10),
        Media char(2) not null);

create table tracks(sernum number not null,
        song varchar2(50) not null,
        primary key(sernum, song),
        foreign key(sernum) references albums(sernum));

create table performers(sernum number not null,
        Artist varchar2(30) not null,
        Instrument varchar2(50) not null,
        primary key(sernum, Artist, Instrument),
        foreign key (sernum) references albums(sernum));
```

I want to perform two queries in sql oracle:

- list the names of the artists that used all instruments.
- list the names of the albums containing the maximum number or songs.

here is my tries:

```
select distinct(a.Artist) from albums a where a.Artist like (select p.Artist, distinct(p.Instrument) from performers p) group by a.Artist, p.Instrument;

select a.Albname from albums a, inner join tracks t on where a.sernum in(select max(t.sernum) group by t.sernum);
```

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you tried?

Comment: @showdev missing expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Query 1 - get artists who have played all instruments:**

```
SELECT
  p.Artist
FROM
  (
    SELECT Artist, count(distinct Instrument) as InstrumentCount
    FROM performers
    GROUP BY artist
  ) p
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Instrument) as InstrumentCount
      FROM performers
    ) i
    ON p.InstrumentCount = i.InstrumentCount
```

**Explanation**: 1st subquery gets the count of instruments played by each artist.  2nd subquery gets the count of unique instruments.  The two are joined together based on this instrument count to give us only those artists whose instrument counts match the maximum.

--

**Query 2 - Get albums containing the maximum number of songs:**

```
WITH
AlbumTrackCount
(
  SELECT
    sernum,
    COUNT(1) as TrackCount
  FROM tracks
  GROUP BY sernum
)
SELECT
  a.Albname
FROM albums a
  JOIN AlbumTrackCount atc
    ON a.sernum = atc.sernum
    AND atc.TrackCount =
      (
        SELECT MAX(TrackCount)
        FROM AlbumTrackCount
      )
```

**Explanation**: the WITH up top establishes a subquery we'll reuse; it gets us the track count within each album.  Down below, we join the albums with this album track count, and add a filter that only those albums with a track count equal to the maximum track count *of any of the albums*.  Note that this is different from the top query, which just got every instrument ever; here, it is important to first count up the tracks within each album, and then get the maximum of those counts.

Comment: You might want to review the suggestions for answering [homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Generally, it is preferred to guide the OP in the right direction, rather than provide a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Below are some of the issues with your queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.artist)
FROM   albums a
WHERE  a.artist LIKE (SELECT p.artist, 
                             distinct(p.Instrument) 
                      from   performers p) 
group by a.Artist, p.Instrument;
```

1. `LIKE` indicates that you're going to use a wildcard. When comparing against a sub-query in the `where` clause, you typically use `in` as the operator.
2. `DISTINCT` is not a function. It always applies to all of the columns in a `SELECT` statement.
3. `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` serve very similar purposes. You would rarely use both in the same statement.
4. You can't reference a column from a correlated sub-query (i.e. a query in the `where` clause), in the outer query.

---

```
SELECT a.albname
FROM              albums a, 
       inner join tracks t 
       on 
where a.sernum in(select max(t.sernum) group by t.sernum);
```

1. Your using both a comma and `inner join` to connect two tables. The comma indicates pre-SQL:1999 syntax, whereas `INNER JOIN` is SQL:1999. While, technically you can use both in a single `FROM` clause, you can't use both between a single pair of tables. Also, you shouldn't use both. Sticj to SQL:1999.
2. Your `ON` clause is empty. You should probably be joining your two tables here. If you really want to not have a join condition, change the join to `CROSS JOIN` (to re-iterate: you almost certainly don't actually want this).
3. You have a `SELECT` statement without a `FROM` clause. That is not allowed.